# converting object to string returns [object]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code here, that should output some technical crypto indicators

````
    let rsi = (await alerts.rsiCheck(14, 75, 25, 'binance', 'BTC/USDT', '15m', false));
    console.log(rsi);
    console.log(typeof(rsi));

    let rsiArray = Object.keys(rsi).map(e => ({ word: e, Val: rsi[e] }))

    //console.log(rsiArray[0]);

    let stringrsi = String(rsiArray[0])
    console.log(typeof(stringrsi));
    console.log((stringrsi))

    let test =  stringrsi.split(",");```

after having divided   rsi in 3 objects, I'd like to covert rsiArray[0]... into strings but insted of getting  for eg.  (overBought: false)  i get [object] [object]. What can I do?

even stringify doesn't work
````

Comment: Hi There. Post sample of your `rsiArray`.

Comment: sample? you mean console log?
{ overBought: false, overSold: false, rsiVal: 35.04 }
object
string: { word: 'rsiVal', Val: 35.04 }
string
[object Object]

Comment: What is the value of `rsiArray` ?

Comment: ´´´{ word: 'overBought', Val: false },
  { word: 'overSold', Val: false },
  { word: 'rsiVal', Val: 37.43 }
´´´
rsiArray[0],[1],[2]  divide the values inside brackets

typeof: object

Comment: What is the issue with JSON.stringify(rsiArray[0]) ? It is giving `"{\"word\":\"overBought\",\"Val\":false}"`. Is this not what you wanted ?

Comment: I need to convert it to a string. if I feed rsiArray[0] to .split ill will error out

Comment: `JSON.stringify(rsiArray[0])` is indeed a string. so `JSON.stringify(rsiArray[0]).split` will not throw any error.

Comment: add a working example where you see that it is breaking. Use the snippet editor to add code.

Comment: everything working fine, thanks. 
only weird behaviour- I get "[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart" randomly

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this

´´´
JSON.stringify(rsiArray).split(":");
´´´

gives me:

{ Rsi: 'overBought', State: false },  { Rsi: 'overSold', State: false },  { Rsi: 'rsiVal', State: 51.26 }

I need to treat  the 2 false and the rsi state as separate strings, I need them as part of the logics later in the program, how do I separate these values